# How to run function after script load

Tags: javascript, html, console

I have code:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://example.com/script.js";
document.head.append(script);
loadStuff();
```

How do I run `loadStuff` after loading script?

Comment: script elements have an onload event. You can hook the function call there: `testScript.onload = someFunctionFromScript;`.

Comment: @Shilly not working: Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunctionFromScript is not defined

Comment: then try `testScript.onload = function() { someFunctionFromScript(); }`.

Comment: Oh, it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own very old question:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://example.com/script.js";
script.onload = loadStuff;
document.head.append(script);
```